# Circular reveal animation with css

Tags: javascript, android, css, angularjs, circularreveal

I would create a simple circular reveal animation with css (or eventually with Angularjs since i'm using it in my webapp). What i would is the circular reveal animation like used in Android. The only example i found is in polymer samples: https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/neon-animation?view=demo:demo/index.html&active=neon-animated-pages clicking in "Card" sample and then "Angular". But it's too complicated to include this one in my app. I hoped would possible to do the same thing only with css or ng-animation in a easier way. Anyone can help me? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A way I like to do that is with the Web Animations API. You should use the polyfill for support down to ie8. I understand you probably want to shy away from JS, but this is probably the best way to do it. This link should be able to help you out: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/web-animations-transitions-playbackcontrol/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0 It's a codelab from I/O Google made and it should help you out